# Error while Installing exe file

Tags: .net, vb.net, installation

After completing project in Visual studio 2012, Created setup file and tried to install it in another system.Then it showing an error like this 
[image: here is the screen shot]

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: The screen shot you posted tells you exactly what the issue is. Read the error message and then do the appropriate web searches to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the ProcessingObjectModel.dll file

find the version 11.0.0.0 in gac assembly C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel and add it to bin dir.

Answer (score 0):

You should include the .dll into the distribution package of your application. In other words, the .dll is locally present in your development workstation, but the installation package does not include it when publishing.
You can do that by exploring the property pane of the References of your project and make sure that interoperability types are carried along with your installation package.

Comment: My dll is included in the application but still, I am getting the same error.

Comment: Just for brief, I have one seperate project which is using System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions dll. I have included the reference of Project A to Project B.